# How can we provide onfocus and onkeyup to textarea in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp

How can we write belo textarea code into cakephp using Form->input?
From

```
 <textarea name="tcatname" rows="10" cols="40"  onfocus="javascript:catprint_many_words()" onkeyup="javascript:catprint_many_words()"></textarea>
```

to

```
echo $this->Form->input('tcatname');
```

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using CakePHP myself, but I'm pretty sure you can do it like this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('tcatname', array(
    'type' => 'textarea',
    'rows' => '10',
    'cols' => '40',
    'onfocus' => 'javascript:catprint_many_words()',
    'onkeyup' => 'javascript:catprint_many_words()'
));
```

It's not tested. 
You can look for more info here: [CakePHP formhelper Common options](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#general-input-options).